# Implement as custom widget or try to reuse QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a control that can be used for manual inspection of Tesseract-OCR's output.

Currently I've implemented it as a custom widget, where I do all the drawing (I use a `QScrollArea` to handle the scrolling at least), and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the images are "flowing", like word-wrapped lines in a text editor, and I use the space below the header text, so I don't have 2 clearly separated columns.

Now, it was suggested to me that using a custom widget is 'reinventing the wheel', but the problem is, I don't see a clear way to customize one of the existing container widgets enough to look and behave like this, **that would involve significantly less effort or code**. Neither is it clear at all to me what is the best way to do it. At most, I can think of using a `QListWidget` with owner-drawn items and variable item heights.

Am I wrong to use a custom widget here?

Comment: I think you should use css/html and render it.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Do you mean `QWebView`? But I intend to make it editable later (sorry I hadn't mentioned it) - when the user clicks on an incorrectly recognized image, he will be able to change it. Otherwise this would have been an excellent suggestion.

Comment: Yes, It has 2 advantages : 1. you can use qt signla-slot 2. you can use html event.